# How to return #N/A from Google Sheet App Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-custom-function

This seems like a trivial question. But I have spent some times, I still cannot find any clues from the Internet. I have been trying the work-arounds. They all are not nice. Returning `null` or `undefined` will just result in a blank cell. Of course return "#N/A" (as a string) is far far far from good.

For instance, we have a function in Google App Script.

```
function GIVE_ME_NA() {
    return NA();     // This won't work
}
```

And in cells A1 and A2

```
A1 =GIVE_ME_NA()
A2 =ISNA(A1)
```

The desired results showing in A1 and A2 are

```
    A       B
1  #N/A   TRUE
```

In the sheet formula, we can simply use `=NA()`. But in App Script, I cannot.

Answer (score 1):

At this time it's not possible because the supported return values for custom functions are string, number, boolean and Date.

As you already noticed returning `NA()` doesn't work.

A custom function can't return a formula, user `return '=NA()'`  is set in Google Sheets as a TEXT value until the user manually edit the cell value (or put the cell in edit mode then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Related

- [Throwing custom exceptions and error messages in Google Sheets custom function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26152630/1595451)

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions

Answer (score 0):

What if you

```
return "=NA()"?
```

I'm unclear from the way that you are using this why you want a gas solution, because you are using it as an in-cell function anyway.

If you are doing a normal script, you can use something like this

```
ss.getRange(1,1).setFormula('NA()');
```

Comment: Yes. You are right. Using `setFormula('=NA()')` can achieve this. But in my case it is a bit difficult to change it to the `setFormula()` way. My function takes a Range (one cell, or an array, or a 2D array), check the values inside, and return an array of the same number of items. For example, it takes `A1:D4`. Check the values, some `TRUE` and some `FALSE`. Then return an 4x4 array. If `E1=myFunc(A1:D4)`, it fills `E1:H4`. If `D3` and `D4` are blanks, I want `H3` and `H4` get the values `#N/A`.