# Is there a way to throw a custom error in Google Sheet with built-in formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

**Desired**:

Something like

[image: this]

(*credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75687528/3181104*)

except the error message is entered as a part of a formula within the Sheet.

Imagine

```js
=let(message,"ERROR: input invalid!"
    ,if(not(checkValidInput)
       ,message
       ,))
```

except instead of printing `message` as text onto the cell, throw an error with the `message` being the error text.

How? Help. Please.

Comment: What about `IFERROR()` like `=IFERROR(YourFunction,"ERROR: input invalid!")`?

Comment: I looked into using `browser.msg`  as an error formula result, but it doesn't seem to behave in the same way. Unfortunate.

Comment: @Harun24hr: Thank you for the comment. Doesn't `iferror()` output a text?

Comment: @Argyll yes it would just be error displayed in the cell. I think you're looking for a popup, correct? I don't see a way unfortunately.

Comment: @pgSystemTester: Yes, correct. I changed my question's text a bit to hopefully make the intent more obvious. (Took a long time for the edit to go through.)

Comment: Just to share some feedback, I tried to make a custom formula using a google app script, which could be the formula called if your named formula errored. While the `msg` box worked when called from google app scripts, it does not work when called in google sheets. So I'm not sure there's a solution to this.

Comment: @pgSystemTester: Appreciate you sharing that. Definitely saved me time from attempting to borrow the linked answer for exactly what you described won't work.

Comment: @pgSystemTester That's not a bad idea. `msg` won't work, but `throw`ing the error as written in the linked answer would.